# Show data where year and month but no value showing

Tags: mysql

I want show progress data where year = 2019 and month = 3 but I want to choose highest id to show so my code is like this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM projectmonthlyview2 
 where YEAR(tgl_masuk) =2020 
   And MONTH(tgl_masuk) =3 
   and id IN (select MAX(id) 
                FROM projectmonthlyview2 
               GROUP 
                  BY project_id) 
 Order 
    by project_id asc
```

But not showing any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `projectmonthlyview2` 
where id IN (select MAX(id) FROM projectmonthlyview2 Where YEAR(tgl_masuk) =2020 And MONTH(tgl_masuk) =3 GROUP BY project_id) 
Order by project_id asc
```

Comment: Did you try my answer?  I'm pretty sure it will work and is way better SQL than what you've put.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't exactly clear but maybe this?

```
SELECT * FROM `project_monthly` 
where YEAR(tgl_masuk) =2020 And MONTH(tgl_masuk) =3 
order by id desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: hey i've been solved the issue with the following query